# Simulation-based method to estimate numerical value of the integral

Tags: integration, random-variables, estimation, simulation

Note that this question has two parts: a) where I describe the method I am using and b) the example I do not understand.

**a)**

Let's say that I want to estimate the following integral: $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{x \sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)} dx$$ The idea is that we can write an unknown quantity as an expectation and then approximate it using a sample average relying on the law of large numbers. And so, this integral can be written as: $$E\left[\frac{X \sin^2(X)}{\cos(X)} \right] $$ where $X$ is the uniformly distributed random variable, $X \sim U(0,\frac{\pi}{4}) $. Then the idea would be to:

1. Choose large number of replications $n$ and choose linear congruential generator (LCG)
2. For $i=0,\dotsc,n$:

- Generate $U_i \sim U(0,1)$ using the LCG and calculate $X_i = \frac{\pi}{4}U_i$
- Calculate $\frac{X_i \sin^2(X_i)}{\cos(X_i)}$

3. Output $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{X_i \sin^2(X_i)}{\cos(X_i)} $

**b)**

I am quite confident in this method. However, I have another example that I find rather troublesome. The idea is the same - estimate the numerical value of the integral: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin^2(x)} dx$$ In the solution that I have been provided with it states that we can treat $X \sim U(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ **BUT** in this example instead of writing the expectation as in first example: $$E\left[e^{\sin^2(X)} \right] $$ Rather, I am supposed to notice that I can write the integral as: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin^2(x)} \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2}{\pi}dx$$ And then write the integral as:

$$E\left[e^{\sin^2(X)}\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$$ Then the process of estimating the integral follows the one in initial example.

I'm afraid I do not follow the logic in the second example. Why do I need to add the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ term here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we want to approximate the integral:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.
$$
If $X\sim U[a,b]$, i.e., it is a uniform random variable on $[a,b]$, the expectation of $f(X)$ is given by
$$
\mathsf{E}f(X)=\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{b-a}\, dx.
$$
(assuming that $\mathsf{E}|f(X)|<\infty$.) If $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ are independent copies of $X$, by the strong law of large numbers,
$$
\frac{(b-a)}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)\to (b-a)\mathsf{E}f(X)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \quad\text{a.s.},
$$
as required.

Comment: So the answer to why part b) differs from part a) is that in part b) the factor $b-a$ is correctly accounted for, while in a) it is not.

Comment: in part (a) the integral equals $\approx 0.104$, while simulations yield $\approx 0.132$, that is $0.104 \times 4/\pi$.

Comment: Cool. I get it now. One last thing though - do you know why it was pointed out that we can multiply the integral by one $1 = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2}{\pi}$ since I don't think we explicitly used that anywhere? The way I understand it, $\frac{1}{b-a}$ comes from the pdf of uniform distribution and the limits of integral and so, the $\frac{\pi}{2}  \frac{2}{\pi}$ bit seems not needed?

Comment: It is used to get the equality between the integral and the expectation of $f(X)$.